# Redirect Outbound Traffic to Remote TCP Transparent Proxy

Tags: proxy, iptables, nftables

I want to intercept all the outbound traffic from one Linux host to another host acting as transparent proxy, just for analyzing traffic.

I was doing this by means of nftables with a redirect when the transparent proxy is in the same network:

`nft add rule ip nat OUTPUT tcp dport 1-65535 skuid 0 counter redirect to :8484`

But when the transparent proxy is remotely I need to use another method. What is the correct approach?